# Image is not loading in ImageView - Android

Tags: java, android, android-intent, imageview

I want to load the clicked image in the next activity in fullscreen view. I don't know what I am doing wrong. The app is running completely fine but the image is not loading on the next screen. am new to android development and I thought I should start learning by doing a project. I am not understanding what is the problem in my coding.

```
public class CategoriesAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CategoriesAdapter.ImageViewHolder> {
   private Context mCtx;
   private List<Category> imageslist;

    public CategoriesAdapter(Context mCtx, List<Category> imageslist) {
        this.mCtx = mCtx;
        this.imageslist = imageslist;
    }


    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ImageViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view= LayoutInflater.from(mCtx).inflate(R.layout.recyclerview_images,parent,false);
   return new ImageViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final ImageViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        final Category images=imageslist.get(position);
        Glide.with(mCtx).load(images.url).into(holder.imageView);
        holder.imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent=new Intent(mCtx, LoadWall.class);
                intent.putExtra("url", (Parcelable) imageslist.get(position));
                mCtx.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return imageslist.size();
    }

    class ImageViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
       ImageView imageView;

        public ImageViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {

            super(itemView);
            imageView=itemView.findViewById(R.id.image_view);

        }
    }

}
```

This is the activity where I want to load the image. But its not loading. Please Help

```
public class LoadWall extends AppCompatActivity {
ImageView imageView;
int myImage;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_load_wall);
        imageView=findViewById(R.id.load_image);
        get();

    }
    private void get(){
        if(getIntent().hasExtra("url")){
            String image=getIntent().getStringExtra("url");
            set(image);
        }
        else{
            Toast.makeText(this,"No Data",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
private void set(String image){
    Glide.with(this).load(image).into(imageView);
}
}
```

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Overflow! Titles of questions are required to be descriptive; consider changing it to something like "Image not loading in Android ImageView".

Answer (score 2):

Here you only need to pass URL as a String. Parcelable is not required.

```
intent.putExtra("url", imageslist.get(position).getUrl());
```

Answer (score 1):

Option 1)

In your next activity you are looking for String.

```
String image=getIntent().getStringExtra("url");
```

in first activity in onClick() change your code to this.

```
Intent intent=new Intent(mCtx, LoadWall.class);
intent.putExtra("url", imageslist.get(position)); 
intent.startActivity(intent);
```

As i see imageslist.get(position) will return Category so you will need to add your url parameter. Something like this imageslist.get(position).getUrl();

Option 2)

If you want to get Category object then in next activity change to this

```
Category category = getIntent().getParcelableExtra("url");
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `imagesList` contains data of type `Category` and you send an entry from this list to the next activity. However, the second activity expects a `String` to be received. It will check to see if it has an extra (it has - but not what you need), then try to retrieve that value as a `String` which will result in a `null` String. Having `null`, Glide will not load anything.

In other words, you made a small mistake on what data you use. When you load the data, you do it correctly by using the `url` field

```
final Category images=imageslist.get(position);
Glide.with(mCtx).load(**images.url**).into(holder.imageView);
```

But when you are passing it to the next activity, you send the entire object

```
intent.putExtra("url", **(Parcelable) imageslist.get(position)**);
```

Using the `url` field as you did in the first case will make your app work properly.

Answer (score 0):

Start your `Activity`

```
 Intent intent=new Intent(mCtx, LoadWall.class);
 intent.putExtra("url", images.url);
 mCtx.startActivity(intent);
```